# How to deal with Java regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex

I'm dealing with regular expressions, but I’m not a big fan of it  and I’m obliged to deal with it in my task :(

I have passed hours looking for a solution but everytime I fail to cover all scenarios.
I have to write a regular expression template that supports these patterns:

```
 DYYU-tx-6.7.9.7_6.1.1.0 
 DYYU-tx-6.7.9.7_60.11.11.09 
 DYYU-tx-60.70.90.70_6.1.1.0
```

I feel that this is very simple to do.. So excuse me if it's a stupid question for someone :(

I tried this  pattern but it didn’t work :
`^.*_.*-.*-([0-9]*)\\..*\\..* $`

Any help please.
I will be more than thankful.

Comment: What characteristics of those patterns are you trying to match? `".*"` would match all those patterns.

Comment: Can you explain in words what the pattern is?

Comment: The short answer to "How to deal with java regular expressions?" is "Don't use java regular expressions".

Comment: There is no underscore (_) in your sample data, but there is an underscore in your regular expression.  That seems like a problem.

Comment: DYYU-tx-\d+(\.\d+)+_\d+(\.\d+)+

Comment: I'm just going to add that this also depends on what you _don't_ want it to match.  For example, if leading `0`s except when a single `0` is the component (`01`, etc.) is invalid, the answer will be different.

Comment: for the numbers there's no condition on what to treat as an exception.. below the correct answer..
Thank you every one for your time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
^\w+-\w+-(\d+)(\.\d+)+_(\d+\.)+\d+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0JO0WR/1)

In Java most probably sth like this:

```
"^\\w+-\\w+-(\\d+)(\\.\\d+)+_(\\d+\\.)+\d+"
```

Explanation:

- `^\w+-\w+-` first two parts, e.g. `DYYU-tx-`
- `(\d+)(\.\d+)+_` numbers separated with `.` ending with `_`, e.g. `6.7.9.7_`
- `(\d+\.)+\d+` numbers separted with `.`, e.g. `60.11.11.09`

Answer (score 6):

There are many patterns in the samples that we can use to design expressions. For instance, we can start with this expression:

```
^[^-]+-[^-]+-[^_]+_([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+$
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/SMmzkx/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/SMmzkx/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "^[^-]+-[^-]+-[^_]+_([0-9]+\\.){3}[0-9]+$";
final String string = "DYYU-tx-6.7.9.7_6.1.1.0\n"
     + "DYYU-tx-6.7.9.7_60.11.11.09\n"
     + "DYYU-tx-60.70.90.70_6.1.1.0";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern does not match because you use `.*` which will first match until the end of the string. Then you match an `_` so it backtracks to the last underscore and try to match the rest of the pattern.

Since there is 1 underscore, you want to match a hyphen that comes after it, but there is no hyphen to match after the underscore so there is no match.

Another way to write it could be using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^-]` matching not a hyphen instead of using `.*`

```
^[^-]+-[^-]+-\d+(?:\.\d+){3}_\d+(?:\.\d+){3} $
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[^-]+-` Match 1+ times any char other than `-`
- `[^-]+-` Same as above
- `\d+(?:\.\d+){3}` Math 1+ digits, repeat 3 times matching a `.` and 1+ digits
- `_` Match underscore
- `\d+(?:\.\d+){3}` Math 1+ digits, repeat 3 times matching a `.` and 1+ digits
- `[ ]$` Match a space (denoted between brackers for clarity) and assert end of string

In Java

```
String regex = "^[^-]+-[^-]+-\\d+(?:\\.\\d+){3}_\\d+(?:\\.\\d+){3} $";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hL15rE/1)

Note that in your example data, the strings end with a space, and so there is a space before `$`

Answer (score 1):

```
DYYU-tx-(?>\d+[._]?){8}
```

1. Search for the literal DYYU-tx-
2. Look for 1 or more digits that may be followed by a `.` or an `_` 8 times.

I assumed that it would always start with DYYU-tx- and that it would always be 4 numbers separated by periods followed by an underscore which would then have 4 more numbers separated by periods.

Comment: You don't have to escape `.` inside a `[]` character class.